# PowerShell 7.2.1 New-PSSessionOption OperationTimeout cannot be found on Linux

Tags: linux, powershell, session, timeout

For PS 7.2.1, the same call on Windows and Linux returned different results,

```
New-PSSessionOption -OperationTimeout 360000
```

On Windows it returned a list of params and values, with the OperationTimeout set correctly, 00:06:00.

But on Linux it failed, showing the following error:

```
New-PSSessionOption: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'OperationTimeout'.
```

What's wrong?

On Linux if I issued just "New-PSSessionOption", w/o any param, it'd return a list of params with default values, including ":OperationTimeout: 00:03:00".  So, it's there in the implementation, but why can't I set it?

BTW, I was trying to copy many files, small and big in sizes, from Linux to Windows.  But after the Copy-Item ran for a few minutes, it started failing with "Internal error parsing Wsman fault message...".  That's why I wanted to set this timeout longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you don't need to solve your problem, considering that `OperationTimeout` [doesn't do what its name suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssessionoption):

> **OperationTimeout does *not* impose a time limit on commands or processes running in a remote session** and does not affect other remoting protocols like SSH.

In short:

- [This comment on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15696#issuecomment-873220777) details what this setting actually controls: it is related to how long a remote machine may take to respond to a receive request, but PowerShell simply quietly retries in the event of a timeout. **The tl;dr is: `-OperationTimeout` affects "mostly nothing"**. Arguably, it should never have been exposed to end users.
- Implementing an actual operation-duration timeout is the subject of [GitHub proposal #5434](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5434), which suggest adding a `-Timeout` parameter to `Invoke-Command`.

---

As for your symptom:

- It may be a bug, because even though `OperationTimeout` is specific to [WS-Man/WinRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/portal), the remoting protocol used on *Windows*, you could still be trying to remote into a Windows machine, and the [`New-PSSessionOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssessionoption) doesn't require you to commit to a protocol - only when you call [`New-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession) do you commit to a protocol, such as opting for SSH-based remoting via `-SSHTransport`.
- That said, since it sounds like the setting applies on the *caller* side, conceivably the Linux and macOS implementations of WS-Man may lack it. Generally, this implementation appears to have its problems and may not have a future - see [this blog post](https://www.bloggingforlogging.com/2020/08/21/wacky-wsman-on-linux/).